# Bootstrap to wordpress wont show the image correctly

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to convert a Bootstrap theme into a WordPress theme and WordPress won't show the image. I made some screenshots showing at the left the theme in Bootstrap and the right the one in WordPress.

[image: Bootstrap to WordPress]

And this is my code for the image container in WordPress I don't know what I am doing wrong I have tried everything and nothing works.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" data-fluid=".fluidHeigt" data-float="true">
    <div class="col-sm-5 imageCol">
      <div class="image fluidHeigt" style="background-image:url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/img-our_impact.jpg)">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/img-our_impact.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive visible-xs" />
          </div>
            </div>
```

I have tried to change `class="img-responsive visible-xs"` into `class="img-responsive.visible-xs"` and I get this:

[image: second image]

The styles are both the same for Bootstrap and WordPress so I have exclude the style code as the cause of the problem, also I have noticed that the Bootstrap theme automatically generates this code after the tag style `min-height:799px;` meanwhile the WordPress theme doesn't generate that.

Please someone help me, if you need further information to solve this just ask me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

.visible-xs make the image visible on the extra-small devices only. Try to put this:

```
 <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/img/img-our_impact.jpg"   alt="" class="img-responsive" />
```

Comment: i have tried that and it resizes correctly the length as it should be but the width is to small now , it should be 799px and i get 577px, i need wordpress to generate automatically 799px like the bootstrap theme does

Comment: Is there something in the JS that's possibly generating the height? If so, that may need to reconfigured. Wordpress has a few added js files, so if your JS isn't loaded in the right order, certain things won't work/run.

Comment: Do you have meta name="viewport" tag in the head of your html?

Answer (score 0):

I'd check and see that your Wordpress theme is loading jQuery. If you don't see it, you can put this in your functions.php file to make it load:

```
function my_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

Comment: it didnt work this is how i called my jquery in my functions.php function    function b2w_theme_js() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapmin_js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/bootstrap.min.js' , array('jquery') , '', true);
 wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/bootstrap.js', array('jquery') , '', true);
 wp_enqueue_script( 'main_js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/main.js', array('jquery') , '', true);

 }

add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'b2w_theme_js');

Comment: That's correct for adding js files, but you need to call jquery before all of that in order for those files to work. The snippet I provided will pull in the latest version, or you can go to https://jquery.com/download to download it and add it into your enqueue scripts. 

(PS, this may not be the issue, but that's the first thing I'd check in your scenario - if my js is functioning or not.)